# Why linear displacement is length of the arc?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-kinematics, geometry

I mean isn't the word itself says "linear" meaning straight and "displacement" meaning shortest path between two points?

we even used equations of motion in circular motion like
$v^2  = u^2 + 2a_t(l)$ where $a_t$ is tangential acceleration, $l$ is lenght of arc. But displacement here is not a straight line

but we did problems related to bob and pendulum like

> A simple pendulum of length L is swingging from A to B, forms angle $2\theta$ find the distance travelled and displacement travelled

**Since the motion of the pendulum is also circular why didn't we treat displacement as length of the arc?, we got displacement as chord ($2L\sin\theta)$ rather than an arc, and arc was treated as distance ($2L\theta)$**.
I'm confused regarding this

Answer (score 2):

First I think it is useful to give a brief definition of displacement and distance.
**Distance** depends on the path which an object moves whereas **displacement** is the shortest distance between two points, usually initial and final positions. **Displacement** and **Linear distance** imply the same.

You have mentioned in your question that you have used equations of motion for solving questions regarding circular motion. But you CAN'T use equations of motions unless acceleration is not constant, therefore here you can clearly see $a_t$ is not constant as it changes its direction every second. You may wonder then how to solve such questions. Yes, you have to use this equation but with a slightly different meaning. What is this contradiction. Let me explain.

I wonder whether you have a clear idea about from where these equations of motion come. This is basically from the definition of acceleration. **Acceleration** is defined as rate of change of velocity. This can be shown as,$$\text{rate of change of velocity}=\frac{\text{final velocity} -\text{initial velocity}}{t}$$
$$a=\frac{v-u}{t}$$ where $a$ is constant. From this you can derive $$v=u+at\tag{1}$$
And from the defintion of average velocity,
$$\text{average velocity}=\frac{\text{total displacement}}{\text{total time}}=\frac{\text{initial velocity} +\text{final velocity}}{2}$$
$$\frac St=\frac{u+v}{2}$$
$$S=\frac{(u+v)}{2} t\tag{2}$$ From these two equations you can derive other equations.

Then how do you get correct answer in your question regarding circular motion using that equation? It's simply because your $a$ and $S$ do not have usual meanings here. At this situation your $a$ represents **rate of change of speed** and $S$ represents **distance**. This comes from the definition like before:
$$\text{rate of change of speed}=\frac{\text{final speed} -\text{initial speed}}{2}$$
So you may see $l$ in your equation is not for *displacement*, it is obviously for *length*. Also you can use this equation because the magnitude of $a_t$ is constant, eventhough its direction is not (because the equation we defined is not a vector equation). Thus this conclusion of yours is not correct:

> we even used equations of motion in circular motion like $v^2=u^2+2a_t(l)$ where at is tangential acceleration, $l$ is lenght of arc. But displacement here is not a straight line

Hence, sorry to say, the title of the question is incorrect too.

Comment: thanks for correcting me regarding tangential acceleration, and please excuse my inability to make things clear, for context I was watching this video regarding circular motion and, there the instructor goes [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcDAs.jpg) to compare Linear variables vs Angular variables, he compares $\theta$(angular displacement) with $S$(linear displacement) saying $S = R\theta$, but my question is if its Linear displacement then shouldn't we be taking chord instead or length of the arc?

Comment: @Rambalheartremo, Sorry I didn't watch the video, but I can assure that $S$ in $S=r\theta$ reptesents *arc length*, not *linear displacement*. This confusion arises as you are comparing circular motion and linear motion. $S=r\theta$ or more correctly $l=r\theta$ is a well-known property associated with circles (not with circular motion). See this [wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_sector) for further information. Feel free to ask for further clarification.

Comment: Oh, I first thought link provided by you was for a video, then I looked and found a picture. Your instructor is trying to compare circular motion with ......mmm.... not exactly *linear motion*... that's the problem.. I don't know how to name that motion which is evidently not linear (normally linear means acceleration is constant/straight line motion) , because $v$ represents *speed*, not *velocity*, $S$ represents *distance*, not *displacement*, $a$ represents ......(I have explained this in my answer).

Comment: [This is the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JxttUGnNuCU&t=1210s), you can see he wrote $S=R\theta$

Comment: You may read my comments above carefully. I think they make things clear. The fact is that, we can use corresponding quantities in equations of motions such as speed instead of velocity, distance instead of displacement, rate of change of speed instead of acceleration, etc. But they are no longer vector equations. So there's no need of $S$ to represent a straight line. Your instructor, and many people as well (including me), are doing this.

Comment: @Rambalheartremo , you may find this helpful: https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Precalculus/Book%3A_Trigonometry_(Sundstrom_and_Schlicker)/01%3A_The_Trigonometric_Functions/1.04%3A_Velocity_and_Angular_Velocity

Comment: Please excuse me for raising this silly question, from your definition acceleration is the rate of change of *velocity* with respect to time, but at the same time how do we deduce the definition that it is also the rate of change of *speed* with respect to time,since speed and velocity are not the same? I would be really grateful if you explained that.

Comment: @ACB,please pardon me if you are being mentioned twice,i actually couldn't decipher if the previous comment reached out to you.

Comment: @madness , yes, and now you see? Your question is a duplicate of this.

Comment: @madness, Sorry, I didn't see your comment above before. In reply to that: Acceleration contains direction too but rate of change of speed only contains magnitude only. But magnitudes of both are the same. I think you haven't fully understood my answer. Please grab the idea. What I wanted to convey is that equation we use in circular motion is not the usual vector equation of kinematics.

Comment: @ACB i am extremely sorry for raising this topic again,but i seem to have a doubt on this yet,in the next comment i am explaining it.According to your answer above,the equations of motions are valid for scalers like distance,speed. In the next comment,we see that when we are trying to compute time period using distance travelled by projectile which is $2H_(max)$,the answer turns out to be wrong. Using your $s=ut+\frac{1}{2}at^2$,here $s=2H$=distance,a=9.8 and $u$ is speed,but if we consider $s=0$ as displacement,the answer is correct,so the equation of motion for scalers is not valid it seems.

Comment: @ACB .If we throw a ball vertically upward with speed u and H be the maximum height.Now to find the time period,we would use the equation s=ut−12gt2,here we use s=0 for displacement,so we get t=2ug as desired,but if we use s=2H as distance,it doesn't give the correct answer. Here the path is a straight line with the fact that we go up once and down once,but according to you we could spread the up and down in both directions and that would give us a straight line of length 2H as displacement but it doesn't work,please kindly enlighten me.

Comment: @madness When applying these equations with scalars, we need to care about direction. In your example of projectile, first, ball's velocity decreases, then it increases. So there are two different **rates of change of speed** (since it has no sign±). So you have to apply that equation for the first half and second half separately. Why you are struggling with scalars, while we have vectors?

Comment: My actual concern was why using equations of motion along the circle were valid,and you explained that they were valid due to definitions of distance,speed but i seemed to have found a bit of problems using those definitions in the above problem, could you please show how do we calculate the distance for one direction without using $+,-$ signs which are vectors?I mean for the first half of time period,$s=ut+\frac{1}{2}at^2$,could you please insert the values of $u,a$ in this equation for both directions?

Comment: I am in a dilemma on how to put the values, it is given as $s=ut-\frac{1}{2}gt^2$ but as you said these were scalers i don't understand how $-$ sign came.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misreading the page/slide that you show. I don't think it is saying that linear displacement is the length of the arc. It says linear displacement is $\Delta x$ (*not* $\Delta s$). Although $x$ is not shown in the diagram, I imagine it is referring to a one dimensional linear motion $x=f(t)$ where displacement between times $t_1$ and $t_2$ is $f(t_2) - f(t_1) = \Delta x$. It is contrasting this with circular motion $\theta = g(t)$ where the *angular* displacement between times $t_1$ and $t_2$ is $g(t_2) - g(t_1) = \Delta \theta$.

Although this is not explicitly stated, the *linear* displacement corresponding to an angular displacement of $\Delta \theta$ is the length of the chord between start and end positions i.e. $\Delta x = 2r \sin (\frac {\Delta \theta} 2)$

Comment: I thought the post will help in emphasizing the question but it ended up creating more confusion, in a nutshell i want to know why did we take arc length as linear displacement when it should be a chord of the circle, [maybe this will help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcDAs.jpg). We were comparing angular variables and linear variables and the instructor says linear displacement($S = R\theta$), why did we take arc length instead of a chord, isn't displacement(linear) supposed to be a straight  line?

Comment: @Rambalheartremo Linear displacement is *not* the arc length $s$, it is the chord length; $s=r\theta$ is the distance travelled, not the linear displacement. You misread the slide that you originally included in your post, and the handwritten notes that you now link to in you comment are wrong. Perhaps your instructor mis-spoke.

Comment: [Everyone are saying $S = R\theta$](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0uBOYwixcU0&t=370s) and [I'm currently using this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JxttUGnNuCU&t=1210s), the 2nd one is quite renowned in teaching, but it can't be coincidence that most of them treat $S = R\theta$ , I'm just confused

Comment: @Rambalheartremo Those YouTube videos are wrong - or, at least, using non-standard terminology. What they call "linear displacement" is actually distance, and what they call "linear velocity" is actually speed. Note that the "linear velocity" of a particle in uniform circular motion is constant, so if it were a true velocity then the particle would not be accelerating - which we *know* is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The swing of a pendulum is often approximated by Simple Harmonic Motion (SHM) for small swings, i.e. if $\theta$ is small.  SHM takes place over a straight line.

Even though the pendulum really moves through a distance $2L\theta$,   The displacement, the straight line distance, is  $2L\sin\theta$.
Distance and displacement are almost the same for a pendulum if the angle is small.

[image]